# Load multiple dlls from bin folder using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dll

I am writing an application where in I need a collection of all commandIds. These are present across multiple dlls. I have access to the bin folder.

I used reflection , and was able to do this for one dll at a time

```
Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"T:\Bin\Commands.dll");

IEnumerable<Type> types = Helper.GetLoadableTypes(a);
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    FieldInfo ID = type.GetField("ID");

    if (ID != null)
    {
        string fromValue = (ID.GetRawConstantValue().ToString());

        ListFromCSFiles.Add(fromValue);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to get all the IDs, from all dlls. The Bin folder contains files other than dlls as well.

Comment: So, why don't you parse the `Bin` folder, filter the files by their extension, `.dll`, put them in a `for` loop and execute the code above for each iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need to loop through dlls in the directory.

You also need to make sure you are not loading an assembly that is already loaded.

eg:

```
  string bin = "c:\YourBin";

    DirectoryInfo oDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo( bin );

    //Check the directory exists
    if ( oDirectoryInfo.Exists )
    {
       //Foreach Assembly with dll as the extension
       foreach ( FileInfo oFileInfo in oDirectoryInfo.GetFiles( "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories ) )
       {

                        Assembly tempAssembly = null;

                        //Before loading the assembly, check all current loaded assemblies in case talready loaded
                        //has already been loaded as a reference to another assembly
                        //Loading the assembly twice can cause major issues
                        foreach ( Assembly loadedAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() )
                        {
                            //Check the assembly is not dynamically generated as we are not interested in these
                            if ( loadedAssembly.ManifestModule.GetType().Namespace != "System.Reflection.Emit" )
                            {
                                //Get the loaded assembly filename
                                string sLoadedFilename =
                                    loadedAssembly.CodeBase.Substring( loadedAssembly.CodeBase.LastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 );

                                //If the filenames match, set the assembly to the one that is already loaded
                                if ( sLoadedFilename.ToUpper() == oFileInfo.Name.ToUpper() )
                                {
                                    tempAssembly = loadedAssembly;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //If the assembly is not aleady loaded, load it manually
                        if ( tempAssembly == null )
                        {
                            tempAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile( oFileInfo.FullName );
                        }

                        Assembly a = tempAssembly;
       }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all files of directory by using `Directory.GetFiles`.
After that, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173100.aspx, determine assemblies and use your method for each assembly.