# Loading more dll's into code causes crash

Tags: c#

One of the requirements of the system that I am helping to develop is the ability to import files and we have a set of adapters to process the different types of file (csv, xml etc.) we would expect to encounter.  During the early part of development we were hard-coding the data adapters via reference and using commands. Obviously when this goes live we would want the situation where we could just write a new adapter and throw the dll into a folder and run the procedure without recompiling the code.

To implement this I adapted the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232229/load-multiple-dlls-from-bin-folder-using-reflection). The code in question is located in the constructor as follows

```
string dllLocation = @"C:MyLocation\dllLocation";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dllLocation);
var tempfiles = dir.GetFiles("*Adapter*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);     // This will need to be changed when we go live

    foreach (var file in tempfiles)
    {
        Assembly tempAssembly = null;

        //Before loading the assembly, check all current loaded assemblies in case already loaded
        //has already been loaded as a reference to another assembly
        //Loading the assembly twice can cause major issues
        foreach (Assembly loadedAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            //Check the assembly is not dynamically generated as we are not interested in these
            if (loadedAssembly.ManifestModule.GetType().Namespace != "System.Reflection.Emit")
            {
                //Get the loaded assembly filename
                string loadedFilename = loadedAssembly.CodeBase.Substring(loadedAssembly.CodeBase.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                //If the filenames match, set the assembly to the one that is already loaded
                if (loadedFilename.ToUpper() == file.Name.ToUpper())
                {
                    tempAssembly = loadedAssembly;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //If the assembly is not aleady loaded, load it manually
        if (tempAssembly == null)
        {
            tempAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
        }

        Assembly a = tempAssembly;
```

Later when the method runs we have this

```
private IEnumerable<IUniversalDataAdapter> DataAdapters
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IUniversalDataAdapter))))
            {
                if (type.IsAbstract) continue; // can't create abstract classes

                if (!dataAdapters.Any(y => y.GetType().Equals(type)))
                {
                    IUniversalDataAdapter adapter = (IUniversalDataAdapter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    dataAdapters.Add(adapter);
                }
            }
        }
        return dataAdapters;
    }
}
```

which successfully loads the data adapters and allows them to be used as I would expect.

Now for the question, in the first bit of code we have the line

```
var tempfiles = dir.GetFiles("*Adapter*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If I change it to

```
var tempfiles = dir.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

the routine crashes before the second bit of code runs at this routine

```
private IEnumerable<IDataValidator> DataValidators
{
    get
    {
        if (validators.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDataValidator))))
                {
                    if (!type.IsAbstract)
                    {
                        var validator = (IDataValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(type, context);
                        validators.Add(validator);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return validators;
    }
}
```

Edit: added the exception

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232830
  Message=Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
     at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
     at TTi.Data.Pipeline.Server.Common.DataPipeline.get_DataValidators() in C:\Users\anorcross\Source\Workspaces\Universal System\Data\Main\TTi.Data\TTi.Data.Pipeline.Server.Common\DataPipeline.cs:line 124
     at TTi.Data.Pipeline.Server.Common.DataPipeline.CheckConfiguration(DataConfiguration config) in C:\Users\anorcross\Source\Workspaces\Universal System\Data\Main\TTi.Data\TTi.Data.Pipeline.Server.Common\DataPipeline.cs:line 528
     at TTi.Data.Pipeline.Server.Common.DataPipeline.ProcessDataSource(IDataSource dataSource, DataConfiguration config) in C:\Users\anorcross\Source\Workspaces\Universal System\Data\Main\TTi.Data\TTi.Data.Pipeline.Server.Common\DataPipeline.cs:line 213
     at TTi.Data.Test.Program.ImportTest(String testFolders) in C:\Users\anorcross\Source\Workspaces\Universal System\Data\Main\TTi.Data\TTi.Data.Test\Program.cs:line 362
     at TTi.Data.Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\anorcross\Source\Workspaces\Universal System\Data\Main\TTi.Data\TTi.Data.Test\Program.cs:line 48
     at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
     at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

EndEdit:

The `DataValidators` definately runs before the `DataAdapters` routine. DataValidators are just bits of code contained in the main code base and check to ensure the imported data is of the expected format. At this point we are just loading them so we can make sure the required ones exist.

Looking at the loaded assemblies, both versions of the code load the adapters as required, but the second version loads more than the first as I would expect.

So, why does the second version of `tempfiles` crash at what looks like a completely unrelated part of the code? And if we add enough data adapters will it cause the code to crash?

Comment: What is the exception and stack trace?

Comment: Some questions: Are all files ending with .dll really .net dlls? If you try to load unmanaged dlls it would crash. Are any dlls that are referenced by your dlls in the same place? or somewhere where the system might find them (i.e. the bin folder or %windir%\system32 etc)? Are you running as a 64 bit process and does any of the assemblies you try to load reference a 32 bit unmananged dll (this would also crash)?

Comment: @mortb yes, as far as I can see they are all bits of our code or Nuget packages. The program is unspecific as to 32 or 64 bit and is running .Net 4.6. I am specifically looking in the solution folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception states that required dll was not found so it cannot be loaded. Now which dll he was looking for and why it did not fail on compile? To answer the first question you would need to investigate deeper and eventually you will find that your code is loading some strange dll that you do not use or need. This can happen because of the code that iterates on ALL types from ALL loaded assemblies. It is possible to have as a reference a dll that exposes type that use some types from other dll that you do not reference. And it is fine as long as you do not use that type.

In order to fix this make your loop more specific. It's obvious that your adapter will not be declared in any system dll so why would you iterate those?

```
foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(IsMyAssembly))
            {
                foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDataValidator))))
                {
//...
```

Your first file scan with `Adapter` is better than the one without it because it is more specific. I would advise to make your code even more specific by for example explicit registration of types in some config file this would eliminate dll scan entirely.

Comment: I did want to use the version with adapter, but when I asked I was told we couldn't rely on adapter being part of the name. Seemed odd to me as they are all going to be adapters so why not call them that? I will bring up the idea of using a config file, we are going to have a number of them anyway

Comment: This looks like the problem. I did some counting (which I probably should have done earlier). Without loading anything I had 26 assemblies loaded. With *Adapter* it went up to 32, with exactly 6 adapters coded so far. With just * there were 94 loaded, so presumably somewhere in the extra 62 assemblies there was something dodgy going on. I'll make a non-coding change to the system :)

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same problem when we wrote a function for getting all matching types from a dll. Note the try catch.

```
   private static IEnumerable<Type> MatchingTypesFromDll<TBaseType>(string dllPath)
    {
        try
        {

            return Assembly
                .LoadFrom(dllPath)
                .GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(TypeSatisfies<TBaseType>);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Exception {e} when trying to load from {dllPath}");
                return new Type[] {};
        }
    }
```

We just ignored the exceptions. Even in nuget packages there are some native dlls or possibly files named `.dll` that are not what you would expect. It is less effort to just to catch the exception and ignore the broken file than try to pre-emptively figure out which are managed dlls and which are not.

Comment: I'm interested in understanding why there's an else and if it's ever hit.

Comment: Oooops.. I tried to clean the code to remove some irrelevant stuff. I'll fix it.

Comment: So your advice is to instead trying to filter all of the `dll`s properly and only loading the correct ones, is to catch a generic `Exception`, not like the one the OPs code throws  (`ReflectionTypeLoadException`) and just ignore it? Even though you could have caught any exception?

Comment: I really have no idea what may go wrong when trying to load an incorrect dll. In this case a ReflectionTypeLoadException may be the only one. In terms of our application the best thing to do in trying to load a plugin from a bad dll __no matter what the error__ is just to log it and move on. At some point the exception has to be caught and you can either handle it or kill the app.

Comment: The take-way is that even if you try to pre-filter all dlls before trying to load them and be really clever about it and you test your pre-filtering code with all the types of things that may end up on the list then you still _might_ try to load something that throws an exception. What do you do then? Crash the app or ignore the exception. So in the end you have to put the try catch in there anyway.

Comment: The only other alternative is to provide an explicit list of dlls to load rather than discover them.